# Unclear console error

Tags: javascript, php, css, wordpress

I'm getting this error when trying to enqeue script and styles:
[image]

This is the code in functions.php:

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_enqueue_styles' );
function theme_enqueue_styles() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'parent-style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css' );

    wp_enqueue_style( 'slik-slider-style', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/slik/slick-theme.css' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'slik-slider-style-2', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/slik/slick.css' );

}
function theme_enqueue_scripts(){
    wp_enqueue_script( 'slik-slider-js', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/slik/slick.min.js' );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_enqueue_scripts' );
```

The files are all in places, I have no idea why i'm getting this error...

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: What is the base URL of your site? Is it localhost?

Comment: What is the error code for those GET requests? 404 not found?

Comment: @VolkerK Yes those are 404 errors by the looks of it.

Comment: Do those CSS / JS files exist in your child theme?

Comment: @Enijar : could be 500 server error, 403 forbidden, ...

Comment: the error is 404, and yes my site is local...

Comment: Again, do those CSS / JS files exist in your child theme?

Comment: Yes they do.. in the right place

Comment: Try to open directly one of those CSS, probably they are not accessible for some reason (404 = Not found)

Comment: Make sure your permissions are set properly (I think files ought to be 644).

Comment: sorry, maybe too stupid, but I see `js/slik/` in the path, but the files are named `sliCk.ext` (with a c). Could it be a typo?

Answer (score 0):

There are two things that I see.

First are the two missing css file in the javascript (/js/) folder or are they in a css (/css/) folder. If they are in that path great, if not change the paths to those files.

Second try the following

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_enqueue_styles' );
function theme_enqueue_styles() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'parent-style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css' );

    wp_enqueue_style( 'slik-slider-style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/slik/slick-theme.css' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'slik-slider-style-2', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/slik/slick.css' );

}
function theme_enqueue_scripts(){
    wp_enqueue_script( 'slik-slider-js', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/slik/slick.min.js' );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_enqueue_scripts' );
```

Hope this helps.

Best,

Tim